# "du" shows something takes a lot of space, but what exactly?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk

I have this:

```
$ sudo du -hxd1 /var/log
20K     /var/log/nginx
4.0K    /var/log/lxd
16K     /var/log/unattended-upgrades
108K    /var/log/apt
4.0K    /var/log/sysstat
4.0K    /var/log/dist-upgrade
421M    /var/log/postgresql
27G     /var/log
```

However, none of the directories or files takes even a Gb of space. How can I find out what takes these 27 Gb?

Comment: can you try this command. it will list out the hidden files as well.     du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running " ls -alhS" while root and while in /var/log ?  It could be  an archived rotate file or something else being hidden by one process or other.

The above command will show all files/permissions and sort them by size . File sizes in K/M/G

Answer (score 6):

`du` only displays directory total sizes, not file sizes. Therefore, the files taking up multiple gigabytes would be in the `/var/log` directory, since the total of the directory is being listed at the end, not just the totals of its subdirectories:

```
$ du -hxd1
184K ./proftpd
80K  ./apt
4.0K ./fsck
12M  ./nginx
155M .
```

`du -axh` will list all files with human-readability, which can be sorted: `du -axh | sort -h`.

```
$ du -axh | sort -h # some entries snipped for readability
4.0K    ./proftpd/proftpd.log
4.0K    ./proftpd/proftpd.log.2.gz
8.0K    ./auth.log.2.gz
8.0K    ./auth.log.3.gz
8.0K    ./auth.log.4.gz
8.0K    ./faillog
12K     ./mail.warn
53M     ./mail.info.1
53M     ./mail.log.1
155M    .
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets execute some of the commands and see what results I am expecting .This is from my own Unix Directory

```
du -mh /data/project/seth_support/seth
```

it is bringing out all the contents of the files and directories inside seth & showing the size in Mb . The last line shows the total size of the Directory in Mb which is 930 MB. If I add up the sizes of the files & directories then it is coming to 930 MB as well.

Now

```
du -sh /data/project/seth_support/seth
```

also shows the last line and brings out the size of 930 MB as well .

In your case I am not sure of the command option du -hxd1 . When I am executing it shows invalid option . Please ask your System Admin about the unclear space of 27 GB .

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the program `ncdu`, a disk usage analyzer with an ncurses interface. [ncdu homepage](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu)

It will recursively start scanning directories from the provided start path (or the current directory if none is provided).

Highlights:

- Small install size
- No desktop required
- Graphical representation of relative size
- Can navigate directory structure
- Can delete items

Answer (score -1):

“du” (Disk Usage) is a standard Unix/Linux command, used to check the information of disk usage of files and directories on a machine.  The du command also displays the files and directory sizes in a recursively manner.

du -h /directory name (-h is for Human readable format . Means you can see sizes in Bytes, Kilobytes, Megabytes, Gigabytes etc.)

du -sh /directory name ( summary of a grand total disk usage size of an directory )

du -ah /directory name ( almost the same as -h)

du - k / directory name (in kilobytes)

du -mh / directory name ( in Megabytes)

There are even more options but the above is more frequently used .

Comment: This does not answer the question _How can I find out what takes these 27 Gb?_

Comment: Please check the answer if it suffices you or else ask Sys Admin of the Server.

Comment: U&L is a knowledge base; answers should be such that users having similar question could benefit from the answer. _ask Sys Admin of the Server._ is not the kind of answer that is wanted here.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint ... I tried out my own and even gave the answer whatever feasible . I told to ask admin bcoz sometimes we ourselves do it from our side .